# $BASHPID And $$ differ in some cases

Tags: bash, shell, process, parameter, subshell

I'm reading "BASH pocket guide of Oreilly".
It said:

> The process ID of the current Bash process.
>   In some cases, this can differ from $$.

Above explanation , explained `$BASHPID` variable.

**Question:** which cases?

Comment: It should be noted that `$BASHPID` is new to BASH 4. If you are using BASH 3.x, you have to use `$$`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An example is provided in the `BASHPID` description of the bash manpage:

```
   BASHPID
          Expands to the process id of the  current  bash  process.   This
          differs  from  $$ under certain circumstances, such as subshells
          that do not require bash to be re-initialized.
```

Here is an example of a subshell outputting the contents of the variable, along with `$$` and the contents of `BASHPID` outside of the subshell.

```
$ echo $(echo $BASHPID $$)      $$       $BASHPID
              25680    16920    16920    16920
#             |        |        |        |
#             |        |        |        -- $BASHPID outside of the subshell
#             |        |        -- $$ outside of the subshell
#             |        -- $$ inside of the subshell
#             -- $BASHPID inside of the subshell
```

Answer (score 16):

Subshells. `$$` is specified by POSIX and always remains the value of the original shell process. `$BASHPID` is a Bash-specific variable, and is always the value of the process from which the variable is dereferenced, counting subshells.

```
 $ f() { printf '%s: %d, %d\n' "$1" $$ $BASHPID; };
 $ ${BASH_VERSION+shopt -s lastpipe}; set +m;
 $ f 1 >&2 | f 2
2: 31490, 31490
1: 31490, 32545
```

I did manage to convince the mksh maintainer to add `BASHPID` to the most recent version, so it is somewhat portable. It is also possible to implement `BASHPID` in ksh93 yourself on many platforms.

Comment: Why using `${BASH_VERSION+shopt -s lastpipe}` and not more simply `shopt -s lastpipe`?

Comment: @TheQuark Only bash has `shopt`, and only bash (and ksh93v-) have configurable "lastpipe" behavior, though their defaults are backwards. `${var+}` isn't a particularly good mechanism either because it's being field split. It works alright for string literals with a known `IFS` when used at the top of scripts that aren't being sourced by other scripts.