# Subshell does not create a separate process

Tags: process, subshell

I have a `./scr` script.

```
abc@~ $ cat scr
#!/bin/bash
ps
echo '-------'
echo "$(ps)"

abc@~ $
```

My goal is to find out how are the subprocesses created.
As far as I know, the `$(...)` part should create a subshell, and therefore a new process. So the number of processes in the second call of `ps` should be larger.

That's exactly how it is if I source the script in the current shell:

```
abc@~ $ . scr
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1659 ttys000    0:00.17 -bash
-------
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1659 ttys000    0:00.17 -bash
 1785 ttys000    0:00.00 -bash
abc@~ $
```

However, when launching in an interpreting shell, the number of processes doesn't differ:

```
abc@~ $ ./scr
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1659 ttys000    0:00.17 -bash
 1790 ttys000    0:00.00 /bin/bash ./scr
-------
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1659 ttys000    0:00.17 -bash
 1790 ttys000    0:00.00 /bin/bash ./scr
abc@~ $
```

Why is it so?

Similarly, why does `ps` give the same output as `(ps)`?

```
abc@~ $ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1659 ttys000    0:00.18 -bash
abc@~ $ (ps)
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1659 ttys000    0:00.18 -bash
abc@~ $
```

An interesting thing is that prepending the `ps` command with any other command forces it to "produce" the expected new process (produces the expected process in the script at the top, in `./scr`, as well).

```
abc@~ $ (echo 1; ps)
1
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1659 ttys000    0:00.20 -bash
 1823 ttys000    0:00.00 -bash
abc@~ $
```

Is `(ps)` being somehow "optimised" by the shell? And why is it not, when sourced?

*A side note: the system is actually a macOS, I don't expect it to behave differently in that case, though.*

---

### EDIT:

As in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62232/211692), the subshell seems to be a subject to optimisation, and therefore is not being run in a separate, newly initiated shell, because apparently it's not needed.

Why is it needed when running in current shell, then (`. scr`)?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247189/135943, http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/62231/135943

Comment: @Wildcard thanks for the info, I checked the mentioned PPIDs and they do indeed differ in subshells. So the first of my questions is more or less answered, but the inconsistency of this behaviour is still a mystery.

Answer (score 4):

Command substitution happens in "[subshell environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)", not necessarily a full-blown subshell; the shell will avoid creating a useless process if the effect of having a subshell environment can be achieved without it. If you want to see a full-blown subshell, give it something to do which needs a full blown subshell; compare:

```
$ echo "$(ps fax)"
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  ...
 1317 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
 1751 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ sshd: alexp [priv]
 1788 ?        S      0:00      \_ sshd: alexp@pts/0
 1789 pts/0    Ss+    0:00          \_ -bash
 1822 pts/0    R+     0:00              \_ ps fax
  ...
$ echo "$(ps fax; echo)"
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
  ...
 1317 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
 1751 ?        Ss     0:00  \_ sshd: alexp [priv]
 1788 ?        S      0:00      \_ sshd: alexp@pts/0
 1789 pts/0    Ss+    0:00          \_ -bash
 1823 pts/0    S+     0:00              \_ -bash
 1824 pts/0    R+     0:00                  \_ ps fax
  ...
```

Comment: So as I suspected, it's kind of optimised. Isn't such a little unpredictable behaviour unusual for unix, though? Also, the question why sourcing the file creates such process remains unanswered.

Comment: Just to say that the `ksh93` shell does _not_ fork off a new shell instance in the second example. In fact, I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to get it to do that without running it as a background process.

Comment: @DartDega this answer is incorrect; *bash* does fork and creates a new process **everytime** it runs a subshell like `(...)` or `$(...)`; without exception. The optimization is that bash will turn a simple command like `ps` into `exec ps` (when it's the last command in a subshell, and there are no other complications, like trap handlers) changing a fork + exec + wait into a single exec. Since bash will (obviously) also fork each time it runs an external command like `ps; ...`, this means that `(ps); ...` -> `(exec ps); ...` is indistinguishable from `ps; ...`.